# python TypeError: 'list' object is not callable error

Tags: python

I am novice to python and I am trying to understand a basic error here . I am getting a TypeError: 'list' object is not callable error in the below code . Can somebody explain me what is wrong in my code ?

```
graph = {'a': ['b', 'c'], 'b': ['a', 'c'], 'c': ['b', 'd'], 'd': ['a'], 'e': ['a']}


def reachable(graph, node):
    res = [node]
    reachable = graph[node]
    for currentnode in reachable:
        if currentnode not in res :
            reachableNodes = reachable(graph,currentnode) << TypeError: 
            for newNode in reachableNodes:
                if newNode not in res :
                    res.append(newNode)
    return res
```

Error : TypeError: 'list' object is not callable error

Comment: I think a bit more context is necessary - what is this function supposed to do?  How are you calling it?  Note that the indentation of the `return` statement is wrong.

Comment: what is your graph parameter? it seems the graph[node] returns a list object and you call the list instance illegally like functions, and see the danniel's answer

Comment: I have added what graph will look like

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've hidden the function name by doing `reachable = graph[node]`. Use a different name.

Comment: What do you mean hidden the function name . It is a recursive call ? Can you please explain a little bit more

Comment: I don't know what being recursive has got to do with it. You've assigned the list element to the name `reachable`. Only one thing at a time can have that name. So the next time you refer to `reachable`, Python only knows about the list, not the function. Call the list something else.

Comment: @rush00121: Lets put it this way: What do you want `reachable` to refer to in `reachable(graph,currentnode)` (where the error is)?

Answer (score 2):

`reachable` is your module name which you are calling recursively.

At line 3, when you say `reachable = graph[node]`, it overwrites the variable `reachable` which was bounded to a function to be now linked to a list (or what ever).

When at line 6, you try to call the function recursively, it ends up trying to call the list which is what `reachable` is and it fails.

To solve this change the name of the variable, you are intending to hold the list to something different from `reachable`

```
canreach = graph[node]
for currentnode in canreach:
```

Also double check your reachable function. There is a possibility of infinite recursion. Every time you are recursively calling `reachable`, you are creating a new instance of `res`. So `if currentnode not in res` is never false. Try passing res as a parameter, or use it as a global.

Answer (score 0):

**I restarted the Karnel in JpyterNotebook, and have solved the problem without any change.**